# How can I access a scope inside a promise in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So this is my controller:

```
translateApp.controller('translateCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.spinner = false;
    $scope.talkButton = true;

    function redirectRecognizedTextOutput() {
        artyom.redirectRecognizedTextOutput((recognized, isFinal) => {
            if (isFinal) {
                // scope can't be read
                $scope.talkButton = true;
                $scope.spinner = false;
            } else {
                console.log("wait")
            }

        });
    }

    $scope.start = function () {
        // I set spinner and talkButton values and call the function
        $scope.spinner = true;
        $scope.talkButton = false;
        redirectRecognizedTextOutput()
    }
})
```

And my problem is that the `$scope.spinner` and `$scope.talkButton` doesn't work as expected. I tried putting it before the promise and it works. So I tried something like

```
function redirectRecognizedTextOutput() {
    var vm = this
    artyom.redirectRecognizedTextOutput((recognized, isFinal) => {
      if (isFinal) {
        vm.spinner = false;
        vm.talkButton = true;
      } else {
        console.log("wait")
      }
    });
 }
```

But still no changes and no errors. Am I doing it wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `this` != `$scope`? Where exactly do you expect the angular scope to come from (It's not a global variable)?

Comment: @Bergi I updated my question. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I can't believe that "*scope can't be read*". Is there an error message, what exactly does not work as expected? Btw, I don't see any promise in your code, so I don't know what "*putting it before the promise*" means.

Answer (score 3):

maybe the digest cycle might be stopped. i think using `scope.apply()` might fix your problem.

```
function redirectRecognizedTextOutput() {
    var vm = this
    artyom.redirectRecognizedTextOutput((recognized, isFinal) => {
      if (isFinal) {
        vm.spinner = false;
        vm.talkButton = true;
      } else {
        console.log("wait")
      }
      $scope.$apply()
    });
 }
```

Comment: because the promise might cause to stop the digest cycle(which enable the two-way binding between view and model in angular.). in order to manually start it ,there might be slight delay